# Android : How to change seekbar thumb's dimension as seekbar is moved

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-seekbar

Seekbar thumb has to have two circles . Outer circle's dimension has to be fixed while inner circle dimension will grow as thumb is moved along the seek bar.

**Position 1:** 
[image]

**Position 2 :**

[image]

I have created a drawable to be used as thumb :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/gather_seek_bar_thumb_outer_ring"
        android:height="30dp"
          android:width="30dp"
          android:gravity="center">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/gather_seek_bar_thumb_inner_ring"
          android:width="10dp"
          android:height="10dp"
          android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="#48b3ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then on seekbar i am doing this

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) mSeekBar.getThumb();
            Drawable innerDrawable = drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.gather_seek_bar_thumb_inner_ring);
            Rect innerRect = innerDrawable.getBounds();
            Drawable outerDrawable = drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.gather_seek_bar_thumb_outer_ring);
            Rect outerRect = outerDrawable.getBounds();
            int left = innerRect.left > outerRect.left ? innerRect.left - 4 : outerRect.left;
            int right = innerRect.right < outerRect.right ? innerRect.right + 4 : outerRect.right;
            int top = innerRect.top > outerRect.top ? innerRect.top - 4 : outerRect.top;
            int bottom = innerRect.bottom < outerRect.bottom ? innerRect.bottom + 4 : outerRect.bottom;
            innerDrawable.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

But it doesn't change the size of inner circle. Probably because inner-circle is already drawn . Can someone suggest any solution ?

Comment: you can manage it by creating two drawable for both state, in your code "onStartTrackingTouch" you can inflate first drawable and on "onStopTrackingTouch" you can inflate with another layout.

Comment: @farhana "you can manage it by creating two drawable for both state," . The innercircle has to grow as the thumb on seekbar moves. so there will not be just two states. I need to set the width and height of drawable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar_thumb_outer_ring"
        android:gravity="center">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"/>
            <size android:height="30dp"
                  android:width="30dp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/seek_bar_thumb_inner_ring">
        <scale android:drawable="@drawable/seekbarinnercircle"
               android:scaleHeight="100%"
               android:scaleWidth="100%"
               android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Solution to this problem is to use scale Drawable .

```
 LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) mSeekBar.getThumb();
    ScaleDrawable innerDrawable = (ScaleDrawable) drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.seek_bar_thumb_inner_ring);
    innerDrawable.setLevel(5000);
```

On progress listener ,

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) mSeekBar.getThumb();
            ScaleDrawable innerDrawable = (ScaleDrawable)drawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.seek_bar_thumb_inner_ring);
            innerDrawable.setLevel(progress * 100);

        }
```